# Understanding the implications of String over [Char]?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm building a simple class interface for basic parametic polymorphism:

```
class Document a where
  present :: a -> b -> Bool

instance Document String where
  present s o = False

instance Document Int where
  present i o = True

implementation :: Document a => a -> Int -> Bool
implementation v int | int > 10           = present v
                     | otherwise          = False
```

I understand that when numerical arguments to parameters constrained by `Document` you are required to specify their type:

```
print $ implementation (22 :: Int) 400
```

My understanding is that this is due to the compiler not knowing if 22 is an `Int` or a `Float`.

However, I see that the same applies to strings:

```
print $ implementation ("mystring" :: String) 400
```

Again, to differentiate between `String` and `[Char]`. However I don't actually understand the practical differences between these?

I assumed Haskell compiler behavior was similar to C/C++, where all types of `String` were converted to `[Char]` at compile time - is this not the case?

Why would one use `[Char]` over `String` and vice versa?

Comment: There is no difference; `String` is exactly `[Char]`, defined as `type String = [Char]`. String literals can be overloaded with the `OverloadedStrings` extension, though.

Comment: You have another error: `present v :: b -> Bool`, not `Bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between `[Char]` and `String`. The latter is defined as a type alias/synonym:

```
type String = [Char]
```

Both are lazy linked lists of characters. For other representation, there's `Text` which represents strings with contiguous arrays (as in C, roughly, but Unicode aware). We also have `ByteStrings` which however is unsuitable for strings, despite the name: that is a contiguous array of bytes, which can hold binary data. You then need to decode such binary data to reach a real Unicode string. If you know that your characters is latin-1 encoded, you can use a `ByteString`, but for real applications nowadays one should be Unicode-ready.